# Connecting two Azure instances for Azure App Service access

Tags: networking, vpn, azure

So we have a remotely hosted DB for our ERP software (hosted by the software co.) in Azure. Some execs auto-approved a locally-installed/hosted app that must be connected to this DB. Luckily, the ERP folks allow you to connect via an Azure Virtual Gateway VPN. What I am trying to wrap my head around is whether it is feasible to set up this app in App Services and connect it to the VPN VNet. As far as app compatibility goes, that's a complete unknown until they are able to provide me with a piece of test software, but I don't see why it wouldn't work in a container, as it is very simple and has a web interface that can be publicly accessible. However, I need it to be able to connect to the VPN VNet on the back end for DB communications. From everything I've been reading, this should be feasible with select plans on App Services, along with us having to also set up a Virtual Gateway to connect with the vendor's DB instance. Any ideas or experience?

I suppose one other alternative is to just host the app on one of our existing Azure servers (2 DCs and an RDS host), but I've been wanting to keep it as segmented as possible and leverage some of the security features of Azure AD/Identity if at all possible. That and not bog down our existing servers any more than they have to be, as we will be growing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect an Azure Web App to an Azure Virtual Network: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet.

This used to be possible only using a VPN gateway and a point-to-site VPN connection, but it's now a lot simpler if the VNet and the Web App are in the same Azure region and subscription.

The point-to-site VPN connection is however still required if they are in different regions and/or in different subscriptions (which might be your case, since you say the ERP software is managed by someone else; in this case, you will need their support to establish the connection).

Both solutions are described in detail in the article I linked above:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#gateway-required-vnet-integration

Comment: Thanks for the reply! To clarify, the app and vnet should be on our end--but we will be using a VPN connection to reach the other hosted DB in Azure. So by my possibly flawed logic, we should be able to use the integration on the VNet we created for the VPN connection, correct?

Comment: The vendor could also provide a private endpoint (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview) instead of having to use a VPN between VNets (assuming the vendor’s resource is capable of providing that service.

Comment: @GregW Private Endpoints are used by resources in the VNet to directly access the Web App, while instead VNet Integration (with or without VPN) is used by the Web App to access resources in the VNet; they serve in fact opposite (and complementary) purposes.

Comment: I was saying the service provider could publish their service as a private link service to which the customer could connect to via private link.  This would allow all services on the vnet, including the app service that’s integrated into it, to connect to the service the service provider is offering without a VPN.  A better link than the one I posted earlier:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-service-overview